# iPhone SDK 2: UIButton not working in nested views loaded from nib file

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a button in a Nib based view which does not behave like a button (the target method is never called). I have tried to dynamically add the button but it doesnt help.

I will try to describe the app structure (as I suspect it might be causing this issue) and I may not be using the right design pattern.

- View *A* is tied to  Controller *AC*. (loaded from a nib in the root controller and pushed on to the navigation controller.)
- View A has multiple subviews embedded. Lets call one of those A'.
- In the AC::viewDidLoad method:

  I load 3 viewControllers *a,b,c* into member variables of AC.

Depending  on the app settings I *add the view of one of these controllers as the subview of A'*

Essentially in the AC::viewDidLoad method:

```
[A' addSubView:(a.view)];
```

Now a.view has a button (which is tagged).I search for that tag. and Add a target Method to it dynamically.  At this point the a.view is displayed as subview of A' and the button is also visible. Great.

**But touch interaction does not happen** or the touch action is consumed by someone other than my method.

I have tried a lot of variations but the execution never reaches my method. I even tried adding the target to all touchUpEvents. nothing. I checked the control values in the enabled events and that is correct.  That button is simply disabled somehow.
I wrote a simple app with one view and did the same, it worked. So I am thinking it is something to do with the way I am putting multiple pieces together.

*Any Ideas?*

I wish I had something like Spy++ where I could see the message Queue and see who was consuming this messages instead of my app or even look at the class object. I am a newbie to this platform.  [My earlier struggle with this  is on this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947877/iphone-sdk-2-programmatically-adding-an-info-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved it finally!!!  and learnt something in return.  Did cost me a few days to figure this out.

The reason my UIButton object was not working was because I found that in case of a UIIMageView object:

"initWithImage: This method adjusts the frame of the receiver to match the size of the specified image. It also disables user interactions for the image view by default."

AND  *my UIButton had been assigned as a subview of a UIImageView control in the nib file* !!!

There was no errors / warnings. It just gets disabled quietly.

**Solution:** Created a container UIView object which now contains the UIImageView AND the button so that the button appears as overlayed on the Image  but it is actually a sibling of the image and a subview of the dummy container UIView.

Answer (score 5):

Just enable the UIImageView's userInteraction... don't go thru all that craziness!!!

view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 1):

Quick 'sanity check'... Is the button variable not nil when you are assigning the target/selector?

Does the button appear to press down when you press it, and nothing happens ... or does the button never even press down?

Comment: Yes, the button var is ok.  No compile warning/error too.

The button does not press down.  I actually added different pngs to all different states to check that. it doesnt seem to take them at all.

Comment: This resembles very closely a problem i had when adding a UIButton to a custom table section header. The problem turned out to that my target/selector was faulty. If I recall correctly, I hadn't declared my selector properly in my .h file. I would go over the target/selector very carefully and make sure everything is correct..

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-iphone-os-3-0/18343-uibutton-unresponsive-uitableview-custom-header.html

Comment: Method declare as follows - -(void)doAidViewStick:(id)Sender;
Actually If I declare it incorrectly in my litle test app, it crashes..

I also tried hooking it up with an IBAction in the nib. It just stays disabled for some reason.  -(IBAction) doSwitchTohelp;
Tearing my hair out! :-(

Comment: @Dutchie432 I am having a similar problem but my button does "press down" but never calls the IBAction that is linked to the button. Do you have any thoughts on this? I am loading a "popup" view controller from xib so the pop up sits over my initial view controller